# How to show social network providers in OpenInviter?

Tags: 7, emails

Below is the image of all providers.
I have checked postinstall, everything is fine for facebook and others but they are not listed on the providers tab.
How to make facebook available to be able to import contacts from there?
[image]

Comment: I'm also having same question now. Did you got any solution.